# can i have 2 different link settings on Branch.io?

Tags: branch.io

We already set up a branch project, with branch links and it works fine, is it possible to have 2 different behaviors on 2 links on branch?

i am talking about the behavior of the desktop click:

for example, i want that one link will open site A, and another will open site B (not under the same domain)
or to have one link redirect to a web page, and another to be redirected to the  Branch-hosted SMS Landing Page

couldn't find the option on branch.io link settings
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work at Branch. You can definitely have each of your Branch links redirect to different sites.

For a Quick link, you need to update the `Desktop redirect` to the web address you want the link to redirect to.

[image: Quick Links]

For the Branch links you create in the Mobile SDK or using the HTTP API, you can add the `$desktop_url:"http://www.example.com"` parameter to the links.

To learn more about Deep links, you can refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/).